# Rails superclass mismatch error with two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two controllers

one is defined as

```
class Admin::Businesses::DealsController < AdminController
```

it is located at `app/controllers/admin/businesses/deals_controller.rb`

the other

```
class Admin::DealsController < AdminController
```

is located at `app/controllers/admin/deals_controller.rb`

Everything works find in development env but When I push to heroku and the app loads in production env it gives me this error

```
 /app/app/controllers/businesses/deals_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class DealsController (TypeError)
```

related lines from my routes.rb look like this

```
namespace 'admin' do
    resources :deals do
    end
    resources :businesses do
      resources :deals, module: "businesses"
    end
 end
```

Why is it giving me this error, due to same name of controllers ? or super class mismatch ? How can I fix this. I want two controllers for deals one under admin and the other under admin/businesses for business specific actions.

Here is the full stack trace when trying to run the app locally in prod env using
rails s -e production

```
/home/abid/Projects/vocallocal/app/controllers/admin/businesses/deals_controller.rb:1: warning: toplevel constant Businesses referenced by Admin::Businesses
Exiting
/home/abid/Projects/vocallocal/app/controllers/businesses/deals_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class DealsController (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/abid/Projects/vocallocal/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/abid/Projects/vocallocal/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/abid/Projects/vocallocal/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/abid/Projects/vocallocal/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the app start in production env on your local machine? please provide a full trace

Comment: the superclass mismatch means that the class is already defined

Comment: thanks for your input. I am adding the full trace. The app does not start in prod env locally. when I run rails s -e production

Comment: According to the backtrace there is also a (non admin) businesses/deals_controller.rb. What does that look like?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `admin` namespace in your routes is conflicting with your `admin` module in your class hierarchy. The details about why this is causing that specific error are complicated, but are explained in more detail at http://code.dblock.org/warning-toplevel-constant-xyz-referenced-adminxyz

The simplest solution is to rename one of your `admin`s, probably the class name, to anything else.